# CS1002 ; Expected. I have a semicolon

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, syntax-error

I'm following a Brackeys tutorial on making a first person game. And I'm makin the character move script and I'm trying to test but I'm getting error

> CS1002: ; expected.

Heres my code.

```
public CharacterController controller;
float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
Vector3 move = transform right * x * transform forward * z;
controller.Move(move);
```

Comment: Please provide the full source code of your class. Otherwise we can only guess where the syntax error lies. For general c# syntax take a look at the [c# language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction)

Comment: Please provide the line number to get more understanding of the situation. I think it might be at move variable creation. Because you written transform right and transform forward. It is actually transform.right and transform.forwad. A dot operator is there. You missed it.

Comment: Transform (space) forward * z I’d imagine it thinks that’s where it should be cos you typod

Answer (score 2):

```
Vector3 move = transform right * x * transform forward * z;
```

Should be:

```
Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
```

Comment: Still isn't working. error CS0019: Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector3'

Comment: Right, I forgot you were multiplying the vectors by scalars first - change it to transform.right * x + transform.forward * z; and you should be fine. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using dot operator to access the attributes of transform component of the object. In Unity every attribute or method is accessed by dot operator.

You must convert the move variable declaration like this,

```
Vector3 move = transform.right * x * transform.forward * z;
```